# Retry failed tests is not working in TestNg 7.0.0?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

If I run the tests on the version testng 6.14.3 , then the dropped tests are restarted.
If I run the tests on the version testng 7.0.0 , then the dropped tests aren't restarted.

```
    public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

        private int count = 0;
        private static int maxTry = 2;

        @Override public boolean retry(ITestResult iTestResult) {
            if (!iTestResult.isSuccess()) {                      
                if (count < maxTry) {                           
                    count++;                                     
                    iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE); 

                    iTestResult.getTestContext().getFailedTests().removeResult(iTestResult);

                    return true;                                 
                } else {
                    iTestResult
                        .setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);  
                }
            } else {
                iTestResult
                    .setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);      
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor,
        Method testMethod) {
        annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryAnalyzer.class);
    }
}
```

My listener:

```
<listeners>
        <listener class-name="package.AnnotationTransformer"/>
    </listeners>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your implementation and it perfectly works for me (used TestNG 7.0.0). Ensure that imports and class-paths are correct (double-check `<listener class-name="package.AnnotationTransformer"/>`)`.

Also, consider the following, please:

1. There is no need to override `boolean retry()` method of `IRetryAnalyzer` interface. The logic of returning a result (a boolean) dependent on the counter is already defined by TestNG `RetryAnalyzerCount` class (it also implements `IRetryAnalyzer` interface). Thus, it is better to re-use the code of `RetryAnalyzerCount` (with the same logic as yours):

a) by setting the count for maximum retry attempts from within `RetryAnalyzer` class and

b) by overriding `abstract boolean retryMethod(ITestResult var1);` from TestNG `RetryAnalyzerCount` class, which returns a positive boolean result (`true`) if a test failed.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.util.RetryAnalyzerCount;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

/**
 * Used by RetryListener (or AnnotationTransformer) to avoid the declaration of 'retryAnalyzer' in each @Test annotation
 */
@Slf4j
public class RetryAnalyzer extends RetryAnalyzerCount {
    private static final int MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 3;
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1); //used only for logging purposes

    public RetryAnalyzer() {
        setCount(MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retryMethod(ITestResult result) {
       // log example: [15/04/20 13:31] WARN [RetryAnalyzer] RETRY failed test 'displaySearchResultForValidInput' (1 out of 3 times)
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        log.warn("RETRY failed test '{}' ({} out of {} times)",
                methodName,
                this.counter.getAndIncrement(),
                MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS);
       // enough is only the return statement 
        return true;
    }
}
```

2. Leave `AnnotationTransformer` as it is.
3. Ensure `<listeners>` tag in TestNG `.xml` file includes correct path to the listener (`AnnotationTransformer`).

**OR simplify everything:**

a) by deleting `AnnotationTransformer` and `<listeners>` from TestNG `.xml` file and

b) by setting custom `RetryAnalyzer` for TestNG in `@BeforeSuite` (!!! not `@BeforeMethod`, which leads to an infinite loop)

```
@BeforeSuite
    void beforeSuiteSetUp(ITestContext testsContext) {
        setCustomRetryAnalyzer(testsContext);
    }

    private void setCustomRetryAnalyzer(ITestContext testsContext) {
        for (ITestNGMethod method : testsContext.getAllTestMethods()) {
            method.setRetryAnalyzerClass(RetryAnalyzer.class);
        }
    }
```